# switching between scenes freezes touches

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have these two scenes, a menu scene and a main game play scene.
The main game scene has two singelton layer attached to it which is where all of my game stuff is going on.

I use the replaceScene method to switch back from the game scene to the menu scene but when I switch back to the game scene the controls or touches are frozen.

here is the main game scene code:

```
#import "BJPlayfieldScene.h"


@implementation BJPlayfieldScene


+(id)scene {
return( [ [ self alloc ] init ] );
}

-(id) init
{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    //Background Layer
    [self addChild:[BackgroundLayer sharedBackground] z:0];

    //playfiled layer

    [self addChild:[BJPlayfieldLayer sharedfieldlayer] z:5];

}
return self;
}

@end
```

and then the code to switch back and fourth:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0     scene:[IntroLayer scene]]];
```

and

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:1.0    scene:
                                           [BJPlayfieldScene  scene ] ]];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a bunch

Comment: The frame rate shows steady at around 30.0 so I'm suspecting that the touches get disabled when leaving the scene and since the self.touchEnabled = YES; is in my init method it never gets called again since it's a singelton. I tried re enabling it from the outside but with no luck. or maybe the problem is somewhere else all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you implemented onEnter or similar on* method you must call the super implementation. Not doing so will cause "loss of input".

Comment: Thanks, I'm kind of new to this, where would I find the onEnter method and how would I implement it. I have seen the onEnter somewhere but can't remember how it works.BYW I have your book

Comment: I have added an onEnter method and re enabled touches in it and also called the super implementation, but no luck

Comment: ok, I moved the button and menu creation code from the init to the OnEnter and if works!!!! awesome, thanks